# Connecting to Hue via external host

Tags: hadoop, networking, cloudera, hue

I've recently installed hue and am having problems connecting to the interface via an external host, i can connect locally fine. My hue.ini file is configured as http_host=0.0.0.0 http_port=8888. I've seen some posts about how to fix this by setting "Bind Hue Server to Wildcard Address" in Cloudera Manager. I do not have Cloudera Manager, what is the corresponding way to do this in a standalone hue installation?

error.log shows the following

```
[24/Nov/2015 03:02:12 -0800] models       ERROR    error syncing oozie
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/models.py", line 269, in sync
    from oozie.models import Workflow, Coordinator, Bundle
ImportError: No module named oozie.models
[24/Nov/2015 03:02:12 -0800] models       ERROR    error syncing beeswax
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/models.py", line 296, in sync
    from beeswax.models import SavedQuery
ImportError: No module named beeswax.models
[24/Nov/2015 03:02:12 -0800] models       ERROR    error syncing pig
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/models.py", line 308, in sync
    from pig.models import PigScript
ImportError: No module named pig.models
[24/Nov/2015 03:02:12 -0800] models       ERROR    error syncing search
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/models.py", line 318, in sync
    from search.models import Collection
ImportError: No module named search.models
```

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a wildcard address, so you already have "Bind Hue Server to Wildcard Address"  configured. There are thousands of things that could go wrong: network issues, firewalls, etc...

Comment: Ah ok. I am able to connect to other services at the same address and the port is definitely available , any ideas?

Comment: Could you check "netstat -ntlp | grep 8888"? Are you getting errors in browser? Errors in Hue log?

Comment: netstat -ntlp | grep 8888 returns nothing. Hue runserver says "starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ running the same netstat command on port 8000 outputs "tcp     0       0 127.0.0.1:8000    0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN  29224/python2.7"

Comment: Problem fixed, simply ran specified for hue to run on the external ip address as it defaults to localhost. ./hue runserver My_IP